# Coupon code manager

Tags: php, e-commerce

My concern lies in understanding the nature of an object.  My reasoning: when I instantiate my class, I am either creating an entirely new coupon, or I am referencing an existing one from the database. So I am thinking that the new `TJ_Coupon` actually is a new coupon. Am I thus using the constructor correctly?

And then my other question is about abstraction.  How far should I abstract? I have my setters which then go through three functions to actually change the DB.  I am interested in feedback about that flow (seen near the end of the document and moving up).

```
/**
 * Class TJ_Coupon
 * Exceptions
 *              Codes:
 *              0 -> Code Wrong Length
 *              1 -> Bad Date
 *              2 -> Wrong Discount Format
 *              3 -> Uses not positive integer
 *              4 -> Coupon code already exists
 *              5 -> Coupon code does not exist
 *              6 -> Coupon has already been used
 *              7 -> Coupon code is not for current user
 *              8 -> WP User ID is not valid
 *              9 -> Coupon can only be used once per order
 */
 class TJ_Coupon
 {
 /**
  * @var string
  */
 protected $name;
 /**
  * @var string
  */
protected $code;
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $discount;
/**
 * With either a $ prefix or a % suffix
 * @var string
 */
 protected $expiration_date;
/**
* @var int
*/
protected $uses;
/**
 * @var int WP_User ID
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @param $code string coupon code
 * @param $create bool do you want to update database or just instantiate
 * @param $new_coupon array
 * @throws Exception
 */
function __construct($code, $create = false, $new_coupon = array())
{
    $coupons = get_option('tj_coupons', array());

    if ($create) {
        $name = $new_coupon['name'];
        $code = $new_coupon['code'];
        $discount = $new_coupon['discount'];
        $expiration_date = $new_coupon['expiration_date'];
        $uses = $new_coupon['uses'];
        $user = $new_coupon['user'];

        if (isset($coupons["C_" . $code]))
            throw new Exception ('Coupon code already exists', 4);

        $name = $this->check_name($name);
        $code = $this->check_code($code);
        $discount = $this->check_discount($discount);
        $expiration_date = $this->check_expiration_date($expiration_date);
        $uses = $this->check_uses($uses);
        $user = $this->check_user($user);

        $this->update_coupon($name, $code, $discount, $expiration_date, $uses, $user);

    } else {
        if (!isset($coupons["C_" . $code]))
            throw new Exception ('Coupon code does not exists', 5);
        $coupon = $coupons["C_" . $code];
        $this->setName($coupon['name']);
        $this->setCode($coupon['code']);
        $this->setDiscount($coupon['discount']);
        $this->setExpirationDate($coupon['expiration_date']);
        $this->setUses((int) $coupon['uses']);
        $this->setUser((int) $coupon['user']);
    }
}

/**
 * Updates Coupon
 * Make parameters false if you don't want to update that variable
 * @access protected
 * @param string|bool $name
 * @param string|bool $code
 * @param string|bool $discount
 * @param string|bool $expiration_date
 * @param int|bool $uses
 * @param int|bool $user
 */
protected function update_coupon ($name = false, $code = false, $discount = false, $expiration_date = false, $uses = false, $user = false )
{
    if (!$name)
        $name = $this->name;
    else
        $this->name = $name;

    if (!$code)
        $code = $this->code;
    else
        $this->code = $code;

    if (!$discount)
        $discount = $this->discount;
    else
        $this->discount = $discount;

    if (!$expiration_date)
        $expiration_date = $this->expiration_date;
    else
        $this->expiration_date = $expiration_date;

    if (!$uses)
        $uses = $this->uses;
    else
        $this->uses = $uses;

    if (!$user)
        $user = $this->$user;
    else
        $this->user = $user;

    $coupon = array(
        'name'              => $name,
        'code'              => $code,
        'discount'          => $discount,
        'expiration_date'   => $expiration_date,
        'uses'              => (int) $uses,
        'user'              => (int) $user
    );
    $this->update_database($coupon);
}

/**
 * Update Coupon Database
 * @access protected
 * @param $coupon
 */
protected function update_database ($coupon)
{
    $coupons = get_option('tj_coupons', array());
    if (!isset($coupons["C_" . $this->code])) {
        $coupons = array_reverse($coupons);
        $coupons["C_" . $this->code] = $coupon;
        $coupons = array_reverse($coupons);
    } else
        $coupons["C_" . $this->code] = $coupon;
    update_option('tj_coupons', $coupons);
}



/*  Coupon Use Functions
 ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Function to process new price from a coupon without affecting user count
 *
 * @param $user_id string
 * @param $price string without currency symbol
 * @return int
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function process_coupon($user_id, $price)
{
    $coupons = get_user_meta($user_id, 'tj_coupons', true);
    if (isset($coupons["C_" . $this->code])) {
        $coupon = $coupons["C_" . $this->code];
        if ($this->is_used($coupon['uses']))
            throw new Exception ('You have already used this coupon.', 6);
        $uses = (int) $coupon['uses'] + 1;
    }
    else
        $uses = 1;

    if (!$this->can_user_use($user_id))
        throw new Exception ('This coupon is not for you.', 7);

    return array('new_price' => $this->apply_discount($price), 'uses' => $uses);
}

/**
 * Function to use a coupon, affects user count
 *
 * @uses process_coupon
 * @param $user_id int WP User ID
 * @param $price string without $ prefix
 * @return mixed string without $ prefix
 */
public function use_coupon($user_id, $price)
{
    $processed = $this->process_coupon($user_id, $price);
    $uses = $processed['uses'];
    $new_price = $processed['new_price'];

    $coupons["C_" . $this->code]['uses'] = $uses;
    $coupons["C_" . $this->code][time()] = array(
        'use_number'    => $uses
    );

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'tj_coupons', $coupons);

    return $new_price;
}

/**
 * Apply the discount to a certain price
 *
 * @param $price string without currency symbol
 * @return int new price
 */
public function apply_discount($price)
{
    if ($this->is_dollar())
        return (int) $price - (int) substr($this->discount, 1);
    elseif ($this->is_percent())
        return (int) $price * (1 - ((int) substr($this->discount, 0, -1) * .01));
    else
        return $price;
}

/**
 * Checks if the current user can use this coupon
 */
public function can_user_use($user_id)
{
    if ($this->for_user() && $user_id != $this->user)
        return false;
    else
        return $this->for_user() && $user_id != $this->user;
}


/*  Utility Functions
 ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Determines if the coupon is only for a certain user
 * @return bool
 */
public function for_user()
{
    if ($this->user == 'false')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

/**
 * Determines if a coupon is expired by date
 * @return bool
 */
public function is_expired()
{
    if (time() > strtotime($this->expiration_date))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/**
 * Determine if the coupon code has been used up
 * @access public
 * @param $uses int number of times coupon has been used
 * @return bool
 */
public function is_used($uses)
{
    if ($this->uses <= $uses)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/**
 * Determine if discount is by percentage
 * @access public
 * @return bool
 */
public function is_percent()
{
    if (substr($this->discount, -1) == "%")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/**
 * Determine if discount is by dollar
 * @access public
 * @return bool
 */
public function is_dollar()
{
    if (substr($this->discount, 0, 1) == "$")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

/*  Coupon Sanitization
 ========================================================================== */

/**
 * @param $code
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
protected function check_code($code)
{
    if (7 != strlen($code))
        throw new Exception ('Discount code is the wrong length', 0);
    return sanitize_text_field($code);
}

/**
 * @param $discount
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
protected function check_discount($discount)
{
    if (substr($discount, 0, 1) == "$" && substr($discount, -1) == "%")
        throw new Exception ('Bad $ or %', 2);

    $chars = count_chars($discount, 1);
    if (isset($chars[ord('$')]) && $chars[ord('$')] != 1) // Check if the discount has more than one $
        throw new Exception ('Too many $', 2);

    if (isset($chars[ord('%')]) && $chars[ord('%')] != 1) // Check if the discount has more than one %
        throw new Exception ('Too many %', 2);

    if (isset($chars[ord('$')]) && isset($chars[ord('%')])) // Check if the discount has both $ and %
        throw new Exception ('Both % and $', 2);

    if (!isset($chars[ord('$')]) && !isset($chars[ord('%')])) // Check if the discount has both $ and %
        throw new Exception ('No $ or %', 2);

    return sanitize_text_field($discount);
}

/**
 * @param $expiration_date
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
protected function check_expiration_date($expiration_date)
{
    if (!strtotime($expiration_date) || time() > strtotime($expiration_date))
        throw new Exception ('Bad Date', 1);

    return sanitize_text_field($expiration_date);
}

/**
 * @param $name
 * @return string
 */
protected function check_name($name)
{
    return sanitize_text_field($name);
}

/**
 * @param $uses
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
protected function check_uses($uses)
{
    if (!is_int($uses) || $uses < 0 )
        throw new Exception ('Uses is not a positive integer', 3);
    if ($uses == 0)
        throw new Exception ('You can\' have a coupon with 0 uses');

    return sanitize_text_field($uses);
}

/**
 * @param $user
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
protected function check_user($user)
{
    if (!is_int($user))
        throw new Exception ('User ID is not valid', 8);

    return sanitize_text_field($user);
}


/*  Getters and Setters
 ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Set Coupon Code
 * @access public
 * @param $code string
 * @param $update bool if you want to update database
 */
public function setCode($code, $update = false)
{
    $code = $this->check_code($code);

    if ($update)
        $this->update_coupon(false, $code, false, false, false, false);

    $this->code = $code;
}

/**
 * Get Coupon Code
 * @access public
 * @return string
 */
public function getCode()
{
    return $this->code;
}

/**
 * Set Discount
 * @access public
 * @param $discount string (percentage or $ amount) with currency symbol
 * @param $update bool if you want to update database
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function setDiscount($discount, $update = false)
{
    $discount = $this->check_discount($discount);

    if ($update)
        $this->update_coupon(false, false, $discount, false, false, false);

    $this->discount = $discount;
}

/**
 * Get Discount
 * @access public
 * @return string (percentage or $ amount)
 */
public function getDiscount()
{
    return $this->discount;
}

/**
 * Set expiration date
 * @access public
 * @param $expiration_date string ISO 8601
 * @param $update bool if you want to update database
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function setExpirationDate($expiration_date, $update = false)
{
    $expiration_date = $this->check_expiration_date($expiration_date);

    if ($update)
        $this->update_coupon(false, false, false, $expiration_date, false, false);

    $this->expiration_date = $expiration_date;
}

/**
 * Get Expiration Date
 * @access public
 * @return string string ISO 8601
 */
public function getExpirationDate()
{
    return $this->expiration_date;
}

/**
 * Set Discount Name
 * @access public
 * @param $name string
 * @param $update bool if you want to update database
 */
public function setName($name, $update = false)
{
    $name = $this->check_name($name);

    if ($update)
        $this->update_coupon($name, false, false, false, false, false);

    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * Get Discount Name
 * @access public
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set Discount Uses
 * @access public
 * @param $uses int
 * @param $update bool if you want to update database
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function setUses($uses, $update = false)
{
    $uses = $this->check_uses($uses);

    if ($update)
        $this->update_coupon(false, false, false, false, $uses, false);

    $this->uses = $uses;
}

/**
 * Get Discount Uses
 * @access public
 * @return int
 */
public function getUses()
{
    return $this->uses;
}

/**
 * Set Coupon for User
 * @access public
 * @param $user int WP_User ID
 * @param $update bool if you want to update database
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function setUser($user, $update = false)
{
    if ($update)
        $this->update_coupon(false, false, false, false, false, $user);

    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get User for which this coupon is for
 * @access public
 * @return int
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * Get Coupon users name
 * @uses get_user_by
 * @access public
 * @return string
 */
public function getUserName()
{
    $user = get_user_by('id', $this->user);
    return $user->display_name;
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not seeing *blatant* non-OOPness, but there is a little funkiness here:

- The setters ideally should be usable -- and should be *used* -- everywhere you import potential user input into the object.  Since they validate the data before modifying anything, if you use them consistently, you can ensure the coupon's fields are valid without actually having to check if they are every time.

  The problem is that your setters update the database.  Besides the fact that modifying all the fields of a coupon means updating the `tj_coupons` option 6 times, things go sideways if i start with a new coupon and don't set `code` instantly.  The functionalities of setting fields in the coupon and updating the database, should be separated and easily distinguishable.  Perhaps have a public `save()` method or something.
- Your constructor is doing more work than it should.  All it should really do is set stuff up.  You might consider splitting up the functionality to add a new coupon vs retrieving an old one.

  ```
  protected function __construct($coupon) {
      $this->name            = $this->check_name($coupon['name']);
      $this->code            = $this->check_code($coupon['code']);
      $this->discount        = $this->check_discount($coupon['discount']);
      $this->expiration_date = $this->check_expiration_date($coupon['expiration_date']);
      $this->uses            = $this->check_uses($coupon['uses']);
      $this->user            = $this->check_user($coupon['user']);
  }

  public static function withCode($code) {
      $coupons = get_option('tj_coupons', array());
      $C_code = 'C_' . $coupon['code'];

      if (!isset($coupons[$C_code]))
          throw new Exception ('Coupon code does not exist', 5);

      return new TJ_Coupon($coupons[$C_code]);
  }

  public static function create($coupon) {
      $coupons = get_option('tj_coupons', array());

      # I personally prefer failing as early as possible.
      # Here, you fail the instant you see a bad coupon code,
      # rather than doing a bunch of work you're just going to toss out.
      $C_code = 'C_' . $coupon['code'];
      if (!isset($coupon['code']) or isset($coupons[$C_code]))
          throw new Exception ('Coupon code already exists', 4);

      $new_coupon = new TJ_Coupon($coupon);
      $new_coupon->update_coupon();
      return $new_coupon;
  }
  ```

  And then you'd use it like

  ```
  $existing = Coupon::withCode('ABCD1234');

  $created = Coupon::create(array(
      'code' => 'stuff',
      'name' => 'new coupon',
      ... other fields ...
  ));
  ```
- Oh, and as has already been mentioned, `$coupon->update_coupon()` is redundant.  Consider your method names as commands to the object or info about it.  The object already knows what it is; you don't have to tell it.  :)
- The functions like `check_user` and `check_discount`, that do nothing more than validate a parameter against hard-coded rules, other parameters, or data unrelated to the instance, could be `static`.
- An if/else to determine whether to return true or false is largely unnecessary.   Boolean expressions evaluate to a value.  Just return the expression you're comparing or testing.  For example,

  ```
  if (time() > strtotime($this->expiration_date))
      return true;
  else
      return false;
  ```

  can become

  ```
  return time() > strtotime($this->expiration_date);
  ```
- `can_user_use($user_id)` looks like it always returns false.  (`if ((condition)) return false; else return (condition);` could only ever return true if `condition` evaluates to false the first time and true the second.  If that's the case, $DEITY help the maintainer of this code.)

  I might make it look like

  ```
  public function can_user_use($user_id)
  {
      return (!$this->for_user() or $user_id == $this->user);
  }
  ```

  if the logic is as i understand it.
- `check_discount` seems more complicated than it has to be, and a bit error prone.

  - It doesn't do much validation other than counting characters.  The current validation allows for ugliness like `42$50` and `%10$`.
  - Are the chances of someone putting two $ signs, or two % signs, really so high that it's worth having separate error messages for?

  You should probably be checking against a regex rather than just counting chars.  If the regex matches, and it's correct, you can safely assume the input format is valid.  (You might still want to check that the number part is within a certain range, so you don't have 150% coupons.  But you can know for sure that the discount *looks* correct.)

  For example:

  ```
  protected function check_discount($discount)
  {
      $ok = preg_match('/^(\$?)(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)(%?)$/', $discount, $matches);
              # make sure there's a match, with a number and exactly one of $ or %
              if (!($ok and $matches[2] and ($matches[1] xor $matches[3]))) {
                  throw new UnexpectedValueException(
                      "'$discount' doesn't match \$number or number%", 2
          );
      }

      # sanitizing is no longer strictly necessary.  It won't do anything useful,
      # since we've already disqualified whatever it'd clean up.
      return $discount;
  }
  ```
- By the way, note how above, i threw an `UnexpectedValueException` rather than an `Exception`.  (I was originally going to suggest `InvalidArgumentException`, but it's a "logic exception" -- it basically implies that there's a bug in the script, rather than a bug in the input.)

  **Never throw `new Exception`.**  The type of the exception object is itself information about the error, and can be used in a `catch` to differentiate between exceptions you are prepared to handle and ones that should continue to bubble up.  Without that extra info, you basically have to catch everything if you catch anything, and exceptions start becoming too unwieldy to be worth the trouble.

  Always throw some subtype that provides more info about the exception.  Some people will advocate throwing based on the location of the error, and recommend you have a `CouponException` or other such junk.  I don't; to me, that's not much better than `Exception`. But even those people at least ensure that the name provides useful info.  (They just provide the wrong info in that name. :P)  I'd recommend instead throwing exceptions based on the reason behind the error.

  On the other side, you should almost never `catch (Exception $e)` either.  It catches everything, requiring you to disambiguate, and can hide errors that really should have been allowed to bubble up. Instead, catch the types of exceptions you are prepared to handle, and let everything else propagate.

Answer (score 3):

Typically method names on objects do not contain the object type being operated on. For example, instead of `update_coupon`, you would want to name it `update`, as that is what you are doing *to* the coupon. So it would be called like `testCoupon=>update()` The "coupon" part is implicit based on the object you are operating on. A name like "update_coupon" would typically expect a `Coupon` as a parameter to update, ex: `testCoupon=>update_with_coupon(otherCoupon)`.

Along the same lines, `getUserName()` should likely be a `name()` method (or property if there is not extensive processing required to retrieve it, typically) on the `User` object. The `Coupon` should have no knowledge of how to retrieve a `User` object's name.

You might want to stay consistent stylistically as well. Instead of having camel-case `getUserName()` intermixed with underscore-separated names `update_database()`.

Also, with such tight-coupling between the object in question and the database entries, you may want to look into an Object Relation Mapper (ORM) framework to reduce the amount of boilerplate/CRUD code you need to write. Paris/Idiorm is a good one I've used for PHP in the past.